# python request with proxy

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I want to use a proxy with python requests library

```
import requests

proxy_req = {'http':'177.53.57.154:48926'}

url = 'https://www.companyweb.be/en'
ua = UserAgent()
headers = {'User-Agent':ua.random}

r = requests.get(url = url, headers = headers,proxies=proxy_req)

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

I'm getting a response, but the query seems to ignore the proxy (because it's too fast)

I tried this to get the ip and check if it was the proxy ip address:

```
r = requests.get(url = url, headers = headers,proxies=proxy_req, stream = True)
print(r.raw._fp.fp.raw._sock.getpeername())
```

But I get this error :

```
AttributeError: 'WrappedSocket' object has no attribute 'getpeername'
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: you're trying to access `https` site with `http` proxy

Comment: yeah, I changed that : proxy_req = {'https':'103.89.253.246:3128'}. But I get the same error, and it still seems to ignore the proxy, because I get that on my html response : "You have reached the maximum number of searches for free users."
And it shouldn't happen if it was using the proxy and not my own ip address.

Comment: Another note: you have no scheme in your proxy URLs. Documentation says: "Note that proxy URLs must include the scheme." (https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies)